# Refrescar token en interceptor

Tags: angular, https

Necesito controlar la validez de un token, y regenerarlo si hiciera falta, todo esto usando un interceptor, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?.

Mi idea es utilizar la fecha de expiración del token para controlar esto, pero uno de los problemas que tengo, es que a la vez entran dos peticiones al interceptor y parecen no respetarse, consiguiendo que en vez de generar un token, genere 2.

EDITO:

```html
tokenLogin = {
            access_token
            token_type
            userName
            expires
            expires_in
            issued
          }
```

```html
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log(req.url);

    if (req.url.includes('token') && !req.url.includes('api/Login/token')) { // PETICION DE PEDIR TOKEN
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    else if (req.url.includes('api/Administracion/')) return next.handle(req);
    else if ((req.url.includes('xxx') || req.url.includes('xxx')
      || req.url.includes('xxx')) && this.variables.loginCorrecto == true) {
      console.log("Peticiones al servicio");



      let request = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.variables.tokenLogin.access_token
        }
      });

      return next.handle(request);


    } else {
      // SI NO CONCUERDA CON NINGUNA URL SIGUE SU CURSO
      return next.handle(req);
    }

  }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te quedas con lo que encuentras en Internet? Por favor seria posible dee mostrar lo que has buscado/intentado hasta hoy?

Comment: Pues por el momento tengo un interceptor para añadir los token a las peticiones, pero estoy intentando controlar la validez de los mismos mirando su fecha de expiración y creo que la idea es buena, pero no es la forma, edito el post para añadir mi código del interceptor

Comment: Pudieras hacer lo mismo manteniendo el Token en una cookie con fecha de expiracion, haces un auth.guard.ts donde harias tu logica  para validar que el token exista en la cookie, si existe validas que el Token tenga una sesion activa en el server de lo contrario sesion invalida.

Comment: Como hiciste para añadir los tokes a las peticiones, yo no he sido capaz, ya lo tengo guardado en el localstorage